# How does coefficient of correlation differ from coefficient of determination?

Tags: statistical-inference, regression, linear-regression

Let us take two variables in a data set $x$ and $y$ and values be $x_1...x_n$ similarly for $y$. And we are looking into the correlation of $x$ and $y$.

Coefficient of correlation is

$$\rho = \frac{Cov(x,y)}{S_xS_y}$$

And Coefficient of Determination is

$$R^2 = \frac{\sigma_{mean}^2 - \sigma_{fit}^2}{\sigma_{mean}^2}$$

How is $\rho^2 = R^2$.

Comment: It might be worth stating what $x$ and $y$ are in your two expressions. Independent variable? Dependent variable? Predicted values? Residuals? I doubt they are the same thing in both.

Comment: I fixed it a little bit. But does it matter though? Because both coefficients should work to show the relation between $x$ and $y$ regardless of their relation right?

Comment: No - your expression for Coefficient of Determination looks as if it has $x$ as the dependent variable and $y$ as the residual from the linear regression of something unexpressed.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that Coefficient of Determination worked on mean and fit not x and y.

Comment: Perhaps $R^2 = \frac{\sigma_{dependent}^2 - \sigma_{residual}^2}{\sigma_{dependent}^2} = \frac{\sigma_{fit}^2}{\sigma_{dependent}^2}=\left(\frac{\sigma_{dependent,independent}}{\sigma_{dependent}\sigma_{independent}}\right)^2=\rho^2$ ?